# Join múltiplo no R

Tags: r

Tenho duas tabelas: `dados` e `dados_aux`. Necessito acrescentar à tabela `dados` a coluna `REGIÃO`, presente na tabela `dados_aux`. 
Porém, tenho que usar duas chaves para fazer o join: `CIDADE` e `UF`. Caso contrário, as informações ficarão incorretas.
É possível fazer este join com duas chaves usando o `merge()`? Se sim, como seria?

Tabela `dados`:

```
structure(list(CIDADE = structure(c(4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("BOA VISTA", 
"MANAUS", "RECIFE", "RIO DE JANEIRO", "SAO PAULO"), class = "factor"), 
    UF = structure(c(3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("AM", "PE", 
    "RJ", "RR", "SP"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("CIDADE", 
"UF"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Tabela `dados_aux`:

```
structure(list(CIDADE = structure(c(4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("BOA VISTA", "MANAUS", "RECIFE", "RIO DE JANEIRO", 
"SAO PAULO"), class = "factor"), UF = structure(c(4L, 7L, 5L, 
2L, 1L, 6L, 3L), .Label = c("AM", "MG", "PE", "RJ", "RR", "SC", 
"SP"), class = "factor"), REGIAO = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("NORDESTE", "NORTE", "SUDESTE", "SUL"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("CIDADE", "UF", "REGIAO"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode especificar as colunas através dos argumento `by`, `by.x` e `by.y` (caso os nomes das variáveis sejam diferentes entre os `data.frame`). Dessa forma,

```
merge(dados, dados_aux, by = c("CIDADE", "UF"))
```

deve te dar o resultado esperado.